# git delete remote branch not working: branch not found

Tags: git, github, git-branch

I am trying to delete a remote branch in git, I did:

```
git branch -r
...
origin/master
origin/dev
origin/branch_to_delete
```

now I try to delete `origin/branch_to_delete`:

```
git branch -d origin/branch_to_delete
error: branch 'origin/branch_to_delete' not found
```

I did:

```
git fetch --all
```

and tried again, the same error. I tried with `-D` but the same error.

but the branch is there, I can see it in github.com. What to do?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

According to [this post](http://gitready.com/beginner/2009/02/02/push-and-delete-branches.html):

> Deleting is also a pretty simple task (despite it feeling a bit kludgy):
>
> `git push origin :newfeature`
>
> That will delete the newfeature branch on the origin remote, but you’ll still need to delete the branch locally with git branch -d newfeature.

So the error you got just means you don't have a local copy of that branch, so you can ignore it.  Then to delete the remote copy:

```
git push origin :branch_to_delete
```

Comment: thanks. it is so dumb, I thought this will work only if the first step works, but obviously first step was somehow already done.. thanks it worked

Comment: not working. Proofs: error: unable to delete 'github_hub/dev': remote ref does not exist

Answer (score 10):

If you couldn't see it on the server (which is my case, because someone has already deleted that branch on the remote server) but it's still present in your local `.git` repository as the remote branch, you would be able to fix the issue with nor `git push origin --delete [branch]` neither with `git push origin :branch_to_delete`. Instead run the

```sh
git branch --all
git remote prune origin
git branch --all
```

replacing the `origin` with the name of your remote.

Answer (score 4):

To delete a remote branch, the command is:

`$ git push origin --delete [branch]`

It looks like someone forgot the '--delete' in one of the earlier answers.

Comment: While you can use the `--delete` option, the other answer includes a `:` in front of the branch name which will delete the remote branch.

Comment: error: unable to delete 'github_hub/dev': remote ref does not exist

Answer (score 1):

This will be clearer with With Git 2.41 (Q2 2023):

"[`git branch -d origin/master`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/66bf8f19439556da7cf1c8852d07b87257f2a7d9/Documentation/git-branch.txt#L98)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch#Documentation/git-branch.txt--d))</sup> would say "no such branch", but it is likely a missed "`-r`" if `refs/remotes/origin/master` exists.
The command has been taught to give such a hint in its error message.

See [commit 4c643fb](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4c643fb321db00a9c79e2dcd1fd033681333584b) (05 Apr 2023) by [Clement Mabileau (`ctmbl`)](https://github.com/ctmbl).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 66bf8f1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/66bf8f19439556da7cf1c8852d07b87257f2a7d9), 17 Apr 2023)</sup>

> ### [`branch`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4c643fb321db00a9c79e2dcd1fd033681333584b): improve error log on branch not found by checking remotes refs
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Clement Mabileau</sup>

> New git users may want to locally delete remote-tracking branches but dont really understand how they are distinguished from branches by git.
> Then one may naively try: [`git branch -d foo/bar`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/4c643fb321db00a9c79e2dcd1fd033681333584b/Documentation/git-branch.txt#L98)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch#Documentation/git-branch.txt--d))</sup> and get a correct error `branch foo/bar not found` but hard to understand for a newbie, this patch aims to guide one in such case.
>
> when failing to delete a branch with `git branch -d <branch>` because of branch not found, try to find a **remote refs** matching `<branch>` and if so, add an hint: `Did you forget --remote?` to the error message.

So:

```bash
git branch -d -r origin/branch_to_delete
# and
git push --delete origin branch_to_delete
```